# Malicious entity slowly creating accounts on asp.net server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-identity

I'm not sure that this is a stack overflow appropriate question.  If not, I'd appreciate a pointer to a more appropriate forum, as I haven't been able to find one.

I have a small website project that gets a few hundred daily unique users and on average I get one or two people to create an account per day.  Yesterday I noticed that more users were signing up (like about 50) and today another 150 users signed up.  Wonderful, right?  Except that then I noticed that while the emails look legitimate, all of the usernames ended in same letters.  My site requires that email be confirmed before a user gets any additional access and none of these accounts have confirmed their email.  There is no apparent regularity to the creation of these accounts other than that it is happening with slowly increasing frequency.

My first question is, what is the most effective way to prevent this with the least user impact.  The only thing that I can think of is adding a captcha step as part of account registration.  I *really* dislike captcha so if anyone has a better idea for a general solution to this I'd appreciate it.

I'm also interested in this: What could this malicious user be gaining by doing this?  It's not yet anything other than a minor nuisance to me.  The accounts are easily identifiable and they're not (yet) being created at a rate that could represent anything like a denial of service attack.  The only thing I can think is that they're trying to confirm that these emails are registered on my site.  But I can't think why that would be useful.  Also, if the email addresses are real, they're using my site to spam those email, but the spam is a registration confirmation for my site.  So I guess they might eventually get my email provider to shut me down if they keep this up.

Thanks in advance for any help, even if that's a redirect to a different forum.

Other possibly useful information:

- My site is hosted on Azure using asp.net mvc5 with identity framework
- I believe that the emails are legitimate because my email provider
  shows a very small bounce rate (like 1%) on these emails.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 more options which are SMS-Confirmation(by limiting the phone number), and IP restriction.